# JQuery animate with slidedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

My top nav has an animation. While scrolling down it works fine, but the animation comes with fade effect. What i want is  slidedown effect of the background. As scroll doesn't trigger the slide down, Cant make it work like sliding down. can anyone help me?

here is my site:

http://goo.gl/8xt1XZ

and here is my code:

```
$(function() {
var floating_navigation_offset_top = $('#floating-nav').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > floating_navigation_offset_top)
        $('#floating-nav').stop().animate({'opacity':'1'},800).css({'position':'fixed','top': '0', 'z-index': '99'});
    else   
        $('#floating-nav').stop().animate({'opacity':'0'},40);
});

});
```

Comment: "but as scroll don't trigger the slide down" What do you mean?

Comment: Please check the site. I meant when i scroll the slideDown() is not working there. only i found animate() working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, if you want a slide down effect, instead of animating `opacity`, simply animate the `height` from 0 to the height of your slide down menu.

*update:*

Even better, as per  Alexander Lozada's comment, you can use `.slideDown()` function.

```
$(selector).slideDown(speed,callback);
```

*further update:* as requested, here's a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/sphB2/)

*note: for slideDown to work, element should be hidden by JQ methods such as slideUp(), or css  `display:none` etc*

Comment: Alternatively they can use .slideDown instead of even touching animation

Comment: no not working any of the above, you check this http://goo.gl/Sz7sMX to know how i want the slide down of the top nav

Comment: pls check the link if you can give me fiddle.

Comment: thank you!! this works!! it was conflicting with bootstrap navbar's `min-height`!! you saved me!!